# Using CrashAnalytics within an Android Module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have Crashlytics working in my App.

I've added an Android Module to my App named 'engine-module' which has it's own Gradle dependencies.

I don't know how to import the Crashlytics dependency correctly and I just get the following error:

> Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5

What I want to achieve is being able to access 'Crashlytics' from a Class within the 'engine-module' for example:

```
Crashlytics.setUserName("temp user name");
```

**Is this possible? If so, how can it be achieved?**

**Project: build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'
}
```

**App/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

/**
 * Default values for configuration options
 */
def suffixDefault = ""
def versionCodeDefault = 1
def versionNameDefault = "developerBuilt"

/**
 * Android-specific configuration
 */
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flowmellow.projectx
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode project.getProperties().get('versionCode') ? project.getProperties().get('versionCode').toInteger() : versionCodeDefault
        versionName project.getProperties().get('versionName') ?  project.getProperties().get('versionName') : versionNameDefault
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Configurable options
            applicationIdSuffix project.getProperties().get('appIdSuffix', suffixDefault) + ".debug"

            // Common options
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            // Configurable options
            applicationIdSuffix project.getProperties().get('appIdSuffix', suffixDefault)

            // Common options
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Dependencies
 */
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

    //Dependency injection
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(path: ':engine-module')

}
```

**Module: engine-module/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5'
}
```

**SOLVED:**

**Project: build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'
}
```

**Module: engine-module/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define any repositories for the `engine-module` module, this means it cannot resolve the associated dependencies.

Generally people define repositories for their entire project by adding the following code to the root `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        // Add repositories here
    }
}
```

This makes these repositories available for all subprojects.

Comment: Thank you that was my issue, not using the root build.gradle